# How do I Add OnScrollListener to Image gallery demo?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I have found some image gallery demo on below link:
http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-build-an-image-gallery-app-718976/

But it's loading all the images together. How do I add OnScrollListeners to this project?

Comment: Do you want to set scrollView to see all the images by scrolling ?@learner

Comment: My Images are coming from database. Loading all images is slowing the application. I have no clue how to fix it. But I think if I can load images onScroll & only those images which are in focus, it will solve the issue. @ Abhishek kumar

Comment: @ Abhishek kumar - I am new to android development. This is my 3rd application design and I am stuck here from last 1 month. Not able to figure out, how do I load the images from database onScroll & only to those images which are on display. If you can help me, it will be really great.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do code on your Adapter `OnBindViewHolder()` method

This is your Code :

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID()));        
}
```

In the above code `onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)` here `int i` is the position of the image by getting `position` you can perform action within OnBindViewHolder.

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID()));    
    Log.e("POSITION",""+i); //This will show you position on LOG.
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Example : Hiding second position image  
    if(i==2){
       viewHolder.img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

}
```

Note : In RecyclerView `OnBindViewHolder` is calling in every row ,So what you have to do just code inside of the OnBindViewHolder.Its not setting images in a single time Recyclerview getting images by calling OnbindViewHolder for every row and setting the images.

Comment: Thank you so much Abhishek. I will implement it & let you know. Thank you so so much :-)

Comment: First read the documentaion of recyclerView that how it works.(Flow of RecyclerView) I'm just put  here a simple logic to let you know  how its setting  data .

Comment: Sure. Thank You !